# Set connected in the metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $X:=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ (with the metric standard of $\mathbb{R}$) then my question is, a open ball with center in $0$ is connected?

Thank you all.

I'm confused

Comment: How is the open ball related to $X$..? I don't get it.

Comment: $B_\epsilon(0)\cap{X}$ with $B_\epsilon(0)\subset{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: If $x\ne0$ is in the ball, then $\{x\}$ is both open and closed. Note also any open ball with center $0$ contains points other than $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, why $\{x\}$ is both open and closed?

Comment: Is the union over all $n$ or for a particular $n$?

Comment: For $x=1/n$, you can find an open interval $O$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $O\cap X=\{x\}$. You can find a closed one as well.

Comment: @DavidMitra; $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n-1})$, is correct?, thank you.

Comment: @WLOG; Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

No, because suppose that $n$ is the minimal integer such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$.

Then $D(0, \epsilon) = D(0, \frac{1}{n}) \cup \{\frac{1}{n}\}$, and these are $2$ disjoint open subsets of $X$.